# How to create a custom inspector showing a list of lists in Unity?

Tags: c#, list, serialization, unity-game-engine

well, I'm working on a specific part of a game in which I need to create a list of lists, a list of Game levels and in each list node a list of triggers (The level lists and each list inside it are variable in size).
This is all in the script `LevelController.cs`.
This is the Trigger class (it's simple like this for now)

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TriggerClass
{

    public GameObject Trigger;
    public bool Active;
    public int Type;

    public TriggerClass(GameObject obje, bool active = false, int type = 1)
    {
        Trigger = obje;
        Active = active;
        Type = type;
    }

}
```

And a wrapper class to create the Levels List

```
[System.Serializable]
public class WrapperClass
{
    public List<TriggerClass> Triggers = new List<TriggerClass>();
}
```

And of course

```
public List<WrapperClass> Levels = new List<WrapperClass>();
```

I serialized both and they show ok in standard Inspector draw in Unity, but I need to customize the Inspector showing this list, so I made a `InspectorCustomizer.cs` and a `EditorList.cs` in Editor folder.
For now I'm just trying to simulate the default draw that Unity does with the lists (an expand arrow, a size field that creates that amount of list nodes, and in each node the same thing, as I said, the default that happens if you uncomment the DrawDefaultInspector and comment the other 3 lines in InspectorCustomizer.cs)

The InspectorCustomizer:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(LevelController))]

public class InspectorCustomizer : Editor
{

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()   
    {
        //DrawDefaultInspector();

        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorList.Show(serializedObject.FindProperty("Levels"));
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

And here the `EditorList.cs`:

```
public static class EditorList
{
    public static void Show (SerializedProperty list)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(list);
        EditorGUI.indentLevel += 1;
        if (list.isExpanded)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(list.FindPropertyRelative("Array.size"));
            for (int i = 0; i < list.arraySize; i++)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(list.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i));

            }
        }
        EditorGUI.indentLevel -= 1;
    }
}
```

But this just shows the "Levels" list with empty elements, I click in the expande arrow in each element and nothing shows up, I know this happens because the script is iterating only through the Levels list and not each element within, but I don't know how to iterate through every element inside the Levels list to show the same thing.
I'm not really used to serialization so forgive me if this sounds easy.

I cannot do `EditorList.Show(list[i]);` inside the for loop because it cannot apply indexing to a serializedProperty of course, so how do I procced?

Answer (score 3):

No, You don't need the `EditorList.cs`.

[image: Demonstration Image]

[EditorGUILayout.PropertyField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) has a parameter `includeChildren` to show its children properties.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(LevelController))]

public class InspectorCustomizer : Editor
{

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()   
    {
        //DrawDefaultInspector();

        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("Levels"), true);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```